# How to solve in a correct algebraic form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$0.45(x-2) - 0.35x = 4.40$$
I know the answer is $x=53$.

Can someone please help by showing me how to write out the solution in the correct algebraic form (get to "x" by doing the same thing to one side of the = as you do the other side).

Comment: Expand the expression on the left. Regroup the terms with $x$. Move the constant term to the right. Divide to isolate $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$0.45(x-2)-0.35x=4.40$$
$$\implies0.45x-0.9-0.35x=4.40$$
$$\implies 0.1x=5.3$$
$$\implies1x=53$$
or $$x=53.$$

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your reply & solution!! Trying to re-learn algebra to help my child.

Answer (score 0):

We expand the left hand side,
$$
  0.45x - 2\times 0.45 - 0.35x = 4.40,
$$
that is
$$
  0.10 x - 0.90 = 4.40.
$$
Now, we add $0.90$ to each side,
$$
  0.10 x = 5.30,
$$
then we divide the two sides by $0.10$. The solution is
$$
  x = 53.
$$

Comment: Big mahalo Eric!

Answer (score 0):

$0.45(x-2) - 0.35x = 4.40$

Leftmost number is the step number for Steps $1$ to $5$

1. $45(x-2) - 35x = 440$ (multiplying all terms on both the sides by $100$)
2. $9(x-2)-7x=88$ (dividing all terms on both the sides by $5$)
3. $9x-18-7x=88$ (opening the bracket)
4. $2x=106$ (adding $18$ to both the sides)
5. $x=\frac{106}{2}=53$ (dividing both the sides by $2$)

Comment: I appreciate your help Vikram!